# Revolution Slider responsive issue

Tags: wordpress, slider

I'm developing a site on my local. The theme i'm using has revolution slider in it. I have made 3 slides and they are working perfect on my laptop but when i open them in mobile the images layer are not resizing them self. I have search the settings but didn't find any fix.

Sending screenshot here.

```
http://i60.tinypic.com/6jq70p.jpg
http://i59.tinypic.com/3447how.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the `<meta/>` tag.
2. Use the `tp-resizeme` to your image layer.